# get the output of failed job in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've a failed job on Azure Devops that produce an output , this output is consumed on other job with `$[ dependencies.my_job.outputs['Version.GitVersion.SemVer'] ]` if the job fails the output is null is there a way to get the output even the job fails ?